# sed & regex expression

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm trying to add a 'chr' string in the lines where is not there. This operation is necessary only in the lines that have not '##'.
At first I use grep + sed commands, as following, but I want to run the command overwriting the original file.

```
grep -v "^#" 5b110660bf55f80059c0ef52.vcf | grep -v 'chr' | sed 's/^/chr/g'
```

So, to run the command in file I write this:

```
sed -i -E '/^#.*$|^chr.*$/ s/^/chr/' 5b110660bf55f80059c0ef52.vcf
```

This is the content of the vcf file.

```
##FORMAT=<ID=DP4,Number=4,Type=Integer,Description="#ref plus strand,#ref minus strand, #alt plus strand, #alt minus strand">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  24430-0009S21_GM17-12140
1   955597  95692   G   T   1382    PASS    VARTYPE=1;BGN=0.00134309;ARL=150;DER=53;DEA=55;QR=40;QA=39;PBP=1091;PBM=300;TYPE=SNP;DBXREF=dbSNP:rs115173026,g1000:0.2825,esp5400:0.2755,ExAC:0.2290,clinvar:rs115173026,CLNSIG:2,CLNREVSTAT:mult,CLNSIGLAB:Benign;SGVEP=AGRN|+|NM_198576|1|c.45G>T|p.:(p.Pro15Pro)|synonymous GT:DP:AD:DP4    0/1:125:64,61:50,14,48,13
chr1    957898  82729935    G   T   1214    off_target  VARTYPE=1;BGN=0.00113362;ARL=149;DER=50;DEA=55;QR=38;QA=40;PBP=245;PBM=978;NVF=0.53;TYPE=SNP;DBXREF=dbSNP:rs2799064,g1000:0.3285;SGVEP=AGRN|+|NM_198576|2|c.463+56G>T|.|intronic    GT:DP:AD:DP4    0/1:98:47,51:9,38,10,41
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Instead of trying to match what's not there, can you match what's there? For instance, do all the lines that don't start with `#` or `chr` already always start with a digit? In which case you could just write something like: `sed -i "s/^\([0-9]\)/chr\1/" blah-blah.vcf`

Comment: @lurker You are right: it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what is your expected result, try:

```
sed -ri '/^(#|chr)/! s/^/chr/' file
```

Comment: The key bit here is the `!` following the match: the s/// command executes for lines that **do not match**.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single `sed` invocation. The script itself is something like the following.

If you have an input of format

```
$ echo -e '#\n#\n123chr456\n789chr123\nabc'
#
#
123chr456
789chr123
abc
```

then to prepend chr to non-commented chrless lines is done as

```
$ echo -e '#\n#\n123chr456\n789chr123\nabc' | sed '/^#/ {p
d
}
/chr/ {p
d
}
s/^/chr/'
```

which prints

```
#
#
123chr456
789chr123
chrabc
```

(Note the multiline `sed` script.)

Now you only need to run this script on a file in-place (`-i` in modern `sed` versions.)

Comment: This not work for `echo -e '#\n#\n123chr456\nabc' | sed '/^#/ n; /chr/ n; s/^/chr/'`

Comment: @Hazzard17 Okay, so multiline counts and semicolon is not a replacement for a newline, is that your only point?

Comment: The point is two consecutive lines that starts with `#`: in the second `chr` is added.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear and you didn't provide the expected output so we can't test a potential solution but if all you want is to add `chr` to the start of lines where it's not already present and which don't start with `#` then that's just:

```
awk '!/^(#|chr)/{$0="chr" $0} 1' file
```

To overwrite the original file using GNU awk would be:

```
awk -i inplace '!/^(#|chr)/{$0="chr" $0} 1' file
```

and with any awk:

```
awk '!/^(#|chr)/{$0="chr" $0} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```